War movie with fake ally camp
I saw a movie long time back, but I can't recall its name. I remember the plot; please help me with name of the movie.
Movie was about World War. An injured soldier wakes up to find himself in a camp. The camp has the same signs/flags of his own country or ally country. Camp leader assures the soldier that war was over and everything was fine. Camp leader makes things look as friendly to soldier as possible. However, later in movie it is revealed that it was an enemy camp and they wanted to know the war plans from this injured soldier, that's why they acted like his allies, so that he would share his plans and enemy can be aware of next strike. The soldier also is a smart person. He later figures out somehow that it's a setup to fool him. So he probably gives out wrong information.
I do not remember end of movie or any star cast. Hope above is sufficient for someone to help me.

False Flag situation,  a common theme in various genres. I've seen the same in spy, colonial, and even scifi

This is 36 Hours  with James Garner


Germans kidnap an American major and try to convince him that World War II is over, so that they can get details about the Allied invasion of Europe out of him. 
In this psychological war-drama an Army Major is captured by the Germans during World War II. They attempt to brainwash him into believing the war is over and that he is safe in an Allied hospital, so that he will divulge Allied invasion plans.

